# LoDash: Reduce in Angular returns 0

Tags: javascript, lodash

In an Angular controller, I have:

```
$scope.corn = {
        acres: 347.4,
        fertilizer: {
            arm: 0,
            dist: 164.97,
            other: 0
        }
    };

    $scope.corn.fertilizer.total = _.reduce($scope.corn.fertilizer);

    console.log($scope.corn);
```

In the console, I see this:

```
acres: 347.4
fertilizer: Object
    arm: 0
    dist: 164.97
    other: 0
    total: 0
```

I'm pretty sure the statement "_.reduce() is not working" is far from the truth and so, I will instead write

Could someone show a new LoDash user how to use _.reduce to add a totals variable into an object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a callback in the `_.reduce` call. It would look something like this:

```
$scope.corn.fertilizer.total = _.reduce($scope.corn.fertilizer, function(total, num) {
  return total + num;
});
```

The first argument is the collection, and the second is the callback. The callback takes a few arguments, the first is the "accumulator" (which will be the first element of the collection if it isn't defined, which is the case for this example), the second would be the value of the item in the collection, the third is the key or index (which wasn't needed).

Comment: Just to add to Tom's answer, if you want to initialize an accumulator, it would be the third argument to the `reduce` function.  
[lodash docs](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce)

Comment: Ah yeah, should've mentioned that. That's usually what you DO want to do if you're creating anything other than a sum, like a new object or array. Good call.